# Mathematical Mystery 5

Tags: riddle, knowledge

I am like a jewel but I am not so dear

Students have my technical name to fear

Special circles all kiss at my center point

Cosines will give in at a diagonal formula joint

My dual friend is known for an angle or a few

Some of these schools don't teach you that... who knew?

Name the mathematical concept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are talking about a

> rhombus

I am like a jewel but I am not so dear

> rhombi resemble the shape of a jewel

Students have my technical name to fear

> equilateral quadrilateral :D

Special circles all kiss at my center point

> the inscribed circle...? Not sure

Cosines will give in at a diagonal formula joint

> well, the lengths of the diagonals are a direct consequence of the law of cosines

My dual friend is known for an angle or a few

> the "dual polygon" of a rhombus is a rectangle

Some of these schools don't teach you that... who knew?

> Well, mine didn't!

Comment: Yep, that is correct